# File upload and save with different file name using struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to save the file which is uploaded using struts 2 with different filename

orginal filename is like xyz.xls to xyz-jan-01.xls

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files are available as `File`s in the action. Move it using [Commons IO's `moveFile` method](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29).

See the [file upload FAQ entry](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html) and [file upload interceptor docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The code shall look something like this

```
public String execute() {
        try {
            String filePath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads");

            System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, "NewFileName");
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);    //userImage is a File

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

You can find the [complete example here.](http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=18&title=File%20Upload%20&%20Save)